# Tab Mix Plus option Reload Every (seconds-minutes) is listed but its contents are empty

Tags: firefox, browser-addons

If this question has been asked and answered before I am sorry for this post (new here first time).

In `FireFox` using the `Tab Mix Plus` addon, there is an option to reload a tab every few seconds to minutes.  It was working great until this evening.  When I was out of the room my laptop rebooted and now that option in `Tab Mix Plus` is still there but its contents (ability to set reload time for tab) are missing.  I have looked at `about:config` and the setting I had for every 15 minutes is still there listed (900 seconds).

Can anyone lead me in the right direction to fix this?  I use that option everyday and multiple times a day.  I have never had a bit of trouble with `Tab Mix Plus` until this evening.

Comment: What do you mean "missing"? Is the menu option to reload present?